# network access interrupted in MS Access. DB then corrupts.

Tags: ms-access

I connect to a local SQL server with MS Access. I can work without problems for a few days but my database invariably corrupts and I get the error message "your network access was interrupted. To continue, close the database, and then open it again". 
The file size also drops to 0. 
there is no problem with the network.
I'm a new  hire, so with limited knowledge I would think it's an authentication issue. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place for that question, but I am curious -- are you saying you keep an active connection to the SQL Server for days at a time?  You never reboot your workstation?  Also, (almost) any server is bound to have hiccups from time to time.

Comment: I'd say this is better suited for [dba.se]. You should also provide more information. Does the Access database corrupt, or the SQL database? Access should not use a persistent database connection, but create connections when needed. How are you connecting to the database? Any relevant code?

Comment: thank for your reply. To answer your question, I do shut down every day or two.

Comment: and being inexperienced in the admin side of things, I believe it's just the Access DB that corrupts. I can't understand why it would boot me out then drop the file size to zero. I keep the access db on my desktop, to boot.

Comment: Are you the only user of the database? If not, does anybody else lose connection at the same time as you?

Comment: i'm the only user in my department. There's one or two admins who also run queries but they haven't had any problems at all. I don't want to be redundant, but isn't it strange that it file size drops to zero and I can't get back into it at all? I can't help but think it's an authentication error...
"

Comment: If you and the admins are using a shared front end database that could be the cause of it. Are you on a hardwired lan or wireless? Wireless connections are not very reliable for networked access use.

Comment: Authentication errors don't happen after you are connected and working. With an authentication error you wouldn't be able to connect in the first place. To me it sounds like a network unreliability issue. Unlike Word or Excel that only communicate with the source file on save/load, Access maintains constant connection. Is the front end on your computer or on a network share? That sure feels like a bad sync issue.